# React + Material UI + Storybook + Yarn Monorepo - Theme goes back to default

Tags: webpack, material-ui, storybook, yarn-workspaces, themeprovider

**Context**

I'm trying to build sharable custom components (i.e. custom library) using Material UI.
My project is a mono repository with the following structure:

```
/<root>
  /docs (storybook)
     package.json (1)
  /packages
     /material-ui-<lib>
        package.json (2)
  package.json (3)
```

`docs` has the following `dependencies` (1):

```
"material-ui-<lib>": "^0.0.1",
"@material-ui/core": "^4.11.3",
"@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
"@material-ui/styles": "^4.11.3",
"react": "^16.13.1",
"react-dom": "^16.13.1"
```

`material-ui-<lib>` doesn't have any `dependencies`, but the following `peerDependencies` and `devDependencies` (2):

```
"@material-ui/core": "^4.11.3",
"@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
"@material-ui/styles": "^4.11.3",
"react": "^16.13.1",
"react-dom": "^16.13.1"
```

`<root>` doesn't have any `dependencies` nor `devDependencies` related with `material-ui` or `react` (3).

The main technologies used:

- `webpack`
- `material-ui`
- `yarn` (with workspaces)
- `storybook`
- `react`
- `typescript`
- `babel`

**Problem**

When I apply a new theme provider on `docs`, everything works fine, but the moment I import `material-ui-<lib>`, the theme provider gets ignored.

**Tries**

I understand that `@material-ui/styles` is a singleton, so it needs to be addressed as unique. When running `yarn list @material-ui/styles`, I only receive 1 module, not multiple.

I would appreciate your help on this issue.

Comment: Are you using Storybook's Material UI addon? https://storybook.js.org/addons/storybook-addon-material-ui